# How to create key to get a request to Django API?

Tags: django, api

I am creating a database with Django, and I am accesing it with Excel and Apps Script. I can't log in into my superuser account (the only account I'll be having). Therefore, I want to know if there is a way to set a key, or a password, passed through an HTTP header, that I can use to access my API.
Currently I only have one API get method, but I'll have more create, update, etc., and I want to be able to use the same key for these as well. It is a really simple Django application deployed in heroku, so I am not using django-REST-framework, nor graphene-django. So if the solution can come without installing anything else, it would be nice. However, if this is not possible, it is better if the solution comes through graphene-django, since I have used it before, and I am more familiar with it.
It is important to notice that both the excel file and the apps script are private, since I am using django as a database manager for a small, personal project.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [djangorestframework-api-key](https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/)?

The process is as simple as

```sh
$ pip install djangorestframework-api-key
```

```py
# settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = [
  # ...
  "rest_framework",
  "rest_framework_api_key",
]

...

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework_api_key.permissions.HasAPIKey",
    ]
}
```

```sh
$ python manage.py migrate
```

and then your curl should look like this

```sh
$ curl -H "Authorization: Api-Key <API_KEY from admin page>" http://www.example.com
```

Comment: So by making this, any request I make to the page has to have this key right? Or do I have to do something to the requests that I want to only be available with the key?

Comment: Yes, but you can override this behavior per view. Check this part of the documentation: https://florimondmanca.github.io/djangorestframework-api-key/guide/#setting-permissions

Answer (score 0):

REST implementation of Django authentication system. **DJOSER**

[Getting Started with Djoser](https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html)

Also, you need a **MOD HEADER** which is an Extension in Chrome
[Add it from here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en)

Once your `Django` project is up and running go to
`localhost:8000/auth/jwt/create/` for creating `access token` by submitting `username` and `password` (ie: `POST` method)

With this `access token` you need to set it in **MOD HEADER** in **Request Header**  and you are good to go.
it's a JSON web token that's why you need to prefix it with `JWT` and then `access token`

[image: A sample look]